# Capybara test and ajax form create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have this test case:

```
it 'should create new request from ajax form', js: true do
  visit root_path
  click_on 'new-order-link'
  expect {
    click_on 'submit-request'
  }.to change(Request, :count)
end
```

But I'm getting message, that count didn't changed. I suppose, that problem with async. When I add `sleep(3)` after click_on call, everything ok and test passed. But it's sound bad, that I should add sleep call in every test case with ajax.

Comment: prehaps something along these lines would help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11777274/1457871

Answer (score 0):

Try use wait_until { check for some element that is showed after ajax complete }. This will wait until ajax is complete and you can continue to check other stuff.

Edit: I see in capybara 2.0 this method will be deprecated. For more information and how to test in capybara 2.0 check here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby-capybara/qQYWpQb9FzY